# Where to say thanks?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, etiquette

Where is the right place to say "thanks" to all those that answered my question? In a comment to my original post, or in a comment to the latest answer or where?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way to say thanks is to upvote the answers that helped you.

Comment: Accept the one that helped you the most, or even award a bounty to a particularly outstanding one.